# Declare observable array of object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I try to display an array of object, multiple function will have to alter it.
So i try to make it an observable (maybe i'm wrong).

Typescript version : 2.7.2
rxjs : 6.2.1
angular cli : 6.0.8
Node : 8.11.3
Angular : 6.0.7

I have a variable in my service(IsolementService) declared as:

```
public listeIsolements$: Observable<isolementInterface>;
```

I have two main method in my service

```
getIsolements(mydate1:any, mydate2:any){
    let dateToSend = ""
    let headers =  {headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})};
    this.http.post('foo/mywebservice.php', dateToSend, headers).subscribe((data:  Observable<isolementInterface>) => {
        this.listeIsolements$ = data;
    });
}

alteredList(mode:string){
    // Some alteration to listeIsolements$, without http call
}
```

Interface :

```
export interface RENOUVELLEMENT {
    _PERSON_ID?: any;
    _ACTIVITY_ID: string;
    _UF: string;
    _PRESCRIPTEUR_RENOUVELLEMENT: string;
    _ISOLEMENT_CH_STANDARD?: any;
    _ISOLEMENT_COMMENTAIRE?: any;
    _MODIF_MESURE_SOIN_DT_TM: string;
    _MOTIF_MAINTIEN?: any;
    _DATE_RENOUVELLEMENT: string;
}

export interface ISOLEMENT {
    _PERSON_ID: string;
    _ACTIVITY_ID: string;
    _ACTIVITY_ID_FIN: string;
    _NOM: string;
    _PRENOM: string;
    _IPP: string;
    _IEP: string;
    _DATE_NAISSANCE: string;
    _SEXE: string;
    _DEBUT_SEJ: string;
    _FIN_SEJ: string;
    _PRESCRIPTEUR: string;
    _DEBUT_ISOLEMENT: string;
    _FIN_ISOLEMENT: string;
    _UF: string;
    _CHAMBRE_STANDARD: string;
    _RAISON_CHAMBRE_STANDARD: string;
    _PATIENT_INFORME_MODALITE: string;
    _FAMILLE_PREVENU: string;
    _MODE_HOSPI: string;
    _INDICATIONS: string;
    _MESURES_PREVENTIVES: string;
    _CIRCONSTANCES?: any;
    _MED_PRESCRI_SORTIE: string;
    _OBSERVATIONS_SORTIE?: any;
    _RENOUVELLEMENTS: RENOUVELLEMENT[];
}

export interface isolementInterface {
    ISOLEMENTS: ISOLEMENT[];
}
```

My service is call in component :

```
constructor(public IsolementService : IsolementService, public myGestionUserService : GestionUserService) { }
ngOnInit() {
}


/*________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
// Fonction call on submit
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const send_date_deb = form.value['date_deb'];
    const send_date_fin = form.value['date_fin'];
    this.IsolementService.getIsolements(send_date_deb, send_date_fin);
}
```

But when i compile i have a an error TS2495 : type 'Observable'' is not an array or a string type.
Who can i declare what i need ?

Thanks !

EDIT - code of view :

```
<tr *ngFor="let iso of IsolementService.listeIsolements$ | async">
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._NOM }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._PRENOM }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._IPP }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._IEP }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._DATE_NAISSANCE }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._SEXE }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._DEBUT_SEJ }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._FIN_SEJ }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._DEBUT_ISOLEMENT }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._FIN_ISOLEMENT }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell"></td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._PRESCRIPTEUR }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._UF }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell"></td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._CHAMBRE_STANDARD }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._RAISON_CHAMBRE_STANDARD }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._PATIENT_INFORME_MODALITE }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._FAMILLE_PREVENU }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._MODE_HOSPI }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._INDICATIONS }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._MESURES_PREVENTIVES }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._CIRCONSTANCES }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._MED_PRESCRI_SORTIE }}</td>
                            <td class="filterable-cell">{{ iso._OBSERVATIONS_SORTIE }}</td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What is the error trace ? Which line is in error ?

Comment: I have a feeling that you try to bind the list in the view or use it somewhere as an array. The result of the array is the object itself and not the array within that object.So if you want to get the array from `Observable<isolementInterface>` you would want `result.ISOLEMENTS` as defined in your interface.

Comment: @trichetriche My error is in my declaration.

Comment: @Gijs Post, yes i would like to use it as array in my component view, i would like it to be observable so when i alter it in some function my view will update (but maybe i misunderstood a concept)

Comment: @Pylouface Can you provide the code of your view so we can see what happens there?

Comment: Thank you, I know your error is in a declaration. I'm asking you to give us the line in error, because in this code several parts have a declaration issue. The only thing I can tell you is to type your http call with `this.http.post<isolementInterface>` and to remove this typing in your subscription `.subscribe((data:  isolementInterface)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what goes wrong. You make a call, but then you subscribe to it. Subscribing to an observable always return the value of the observable after it emits it. If you want to declare the variable as the observable itself, you simply assign it as the call:

```
this.listeIsolements$ = this.http.post('foo/mywebservice.php', dateToSend, headers);
```

You don't need to subscribe to it if you only want the observable itself. If you want to use the value later on in the view, you can simply [pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) it there (or subscribe to it in the component later on, if thats what you want).

(Edit):
In your view, change it to:

```
<div *ngIf="IsolementService.listeIsolements$ | async as isolements">
<tr *ngFor="let iso of isolements.ISOLEMENTS">
```

Seperate the async pipe from the *ngFor otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I understand why what i did couln't work. I don't have any error, but my data don't display. In order to trigger the request, i need to call subscribe, if i use your syntax listeIsolements is an Observable but don't contain my webservice response

Comment: Angular 'subscribes' to the observable if you pipe it in the view, you don't need to worry about that. If your call's response does not contain the proper model, you might have some syntaxes wrong (i.e. your call returns something else than an isolementInterface )

Comment: 100% right :) I did small syntaxes error in my view. Everything works fine, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
let localArray: Observable<MyObject>[] = [];
```

Context for my solution:
I had an ng table that I wanted to load with data. Then the user could click a row and edit the details. I wanted the table to refresh when they added/updated a bicycle.

HTML:

```
<ng-template #bikesTable>
      <app-bike-table (editBike)="loadBikeFromTable($event)" (deleteBike)="removeBikeFromTable($event)" [bikeDetails]="bikes" [columnHeaders]="displayedColumns"></app-bike-table>
    </ng-template>
```

Observable component.ts

```
export class BikeTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bikeDetails: Bike[] | any = null;
  @Input() columnHeaders: string[] = [];
  @Output() editBike: EventEmitter<Bike> = new EventEmitter<Bike>();
  @Output() deleteBike: EventEmitter<Bike> = new EventEmitter<Bike>();

  selection = new SelectionModel<Bike>(true, []);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loadBikeForEdit(bike: Bike) {
    return this.editBike.emit(bike);
  }
  requestBikeDelete(bike: Bike) {
    return this.deleteBike.emit(bike);
  }
}
```

Wrapping object component.ts

```
  loadBikes() {
    //Load Bikes
    let that = this;
    this.getBikes().then(function (results) {
      that.bikes = results;
    });
  }

  async getBikes(): Promise<Bike[]> {
    let tkn: String | null = this.token.getToken();
    if (tkn) {
      return this._fetchBikesFromBackend(this.bikeService.getBikes(tkn));
    }
    return [] as Bike[];
  }
```

Comment: How do you add to it? Update it?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus, apologies. I didn't see the comment till  today. I added some more context to my answer, but basically you load it with a promise that returns an array.